# Tracking down device in device manager

Tags: windows, usb

I need help in identifying a mystery device in device manager.

I have a strange problem where my Surface Laptop Studio (Windows 11) goes into sleep at random time, even during active use. Reviewing the event log, I see that the event is triggered by "SleepButton":

[Windows Event Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UIAH.png)

I have disabled all auto-sleep in Windows Settings, as well as set the "Power and sleep button and lid settings" to "do nothing":

[Button Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw7Cd.png)

The issue still occurs, making me think that I have an rogue device somewhere.

**Can someone advise how I might go about locating this device (e.g. in the device manager)?**

Thanks,
Tian

Comment: It’s probably about Connected Standby.

Comment: Is there a sleep button on your keyboard?

Comment: No - none of my external keyboards has a "sleep button", and I have also disabled the sleep button to "do nothing" just in case.

Comment: Did you check this thread? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/laptop-goes-to-sleep-mode-while-working-randomly/b13d0481-d92f-4c86-854b-30ae43110a9f

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8 and later: From Start, search for device manager, and select Device Manager from the search results. Troubleshoot the devices and drivers in Device Manager. Note Click Show hidden devices on the View menu in Device Manager before you can see devices that are not connected to the computer.